# При установке пайтон 3.8.6 на виндовс 7 выдаёт вот такую ошибку. Перед установкой удалил весь пайтон с устройства, а ошибка есть. Что делать?

Tags: python

[image: -]

Лог, на который ссылается установщик оставил тут: http://project4190473.tilda.ws

Comment: удалили через unnistal  или ручками del ?

Comment: я написал, что другого пайтона(и других версий) нет

Comment: в реестре тоже ?

Comment: да.............